# is it possible to host a python script who don't use web service?

Tags: python, python-3.x, host

i did a web **scraping** who writes my differents informations in an excel file

my script is really simple:

```
 While True:
1- Take the informations
2- Write it in an excel file
```

It's works with my computer and i try to host it, but when i search how i can host a python script they only talk about django or flask

Is it possible to host a simply code like that? And if its possible, how can i take back my excel file.

I just want a place where my script is turning h24.
I'm sorry if its quite stupid but i tried to search on internet and i don't find my answer on the internet

Thanks

Comment: Well from my experience you would want to have an endpoint to acess this function. The easiest way would be to have a django/flask app. If you were to build a simple flask app you could make an endpoint for you to send the info and it to be downloaded as an xlsx file.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. From your questions I'm assuming that you just need that particulair script to run somewhere, and not have a something call it or access it externally. 

If this is what you're going for you can 'host' your script on any VPS service provider reaally, e.g. Digital Ocean, Heroku etc...

Comment: You have many many solutions for that out there. Try looking for Azure, Google Cloud, AWS, Digital Ocean, they all offer 24/7 virtual machines where you can deploy your script and then retrieve the excel file later on from that machine via SSH or whatever protocol you prefer.

Comment: if you want to send your server requests from say a browser then the server must be visible to the net ...  ovh.com or https://cloud.digitalocean.com/droplets  for about $6/month will rent you a VPS which is a virtual computer in the cloud ... you then copy your code to that machine and launch your server then the outside world can access your server from the ip address of that VPS box as in  `http://1.2.3.4`  or whatever your ip happens to be

Comment: Thanks for your comms, so i think i need a  24/7 virtual machines :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you exactly expect from it... If only run application which sends for example emails or SQL to database it's possible on every physical or virtual machine (your computer too). I started **scraper** which send me notifications on email last year on raspberry pi. In my opinion you would like to have something like virtual server.